# Multi Resolution background images in Flutter assets

Tags: android, flutter, background-image, assets

In Android we have variety of dpi drawable folders so we add background images in that based on resolution. Same like in iOS we add in 1x, 2x and 3x based on screen sizes. But how we will add multi resolution images in Flutter assets?

Ex:

**Android**

```
drawable-hdpi
 - login_background.jpeg
drawable-mdpi
 - login_background.jpeg
drawable-xhdpi
 - login_background.jpeg
drawable-xxhdpi
 - login_background.jpeg
drawable-xxxdpi
 - login_background.jpeg
```

How we add multiple drawables in flutter to support multiple screen sizes without image stretching or scaling?

Comment: you can see my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53864380/how-to-pick-an-asset-according-to-screen-density-dpi-size/63971109#63971109

Answer (score 13):

Flutter defines ratios like ios so, for example, you can create a folder named 0.75x under the assets/images for ldpi images. Other densities are as below

```
Dentisity  Flutter pixel ratio
ldpi        0.75x
mdpi        1.0x
hdpi        1.5x
xhdpi       2.0x
xxhdpi      3.0x
xxxhdpi     4.0x
```

[See documentation here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/flutter-for/android-devs#where-do-i-store-my-resolution-dependent-image-files)

Comment: So if i use assets/2.0x/icon.png for hdpi, and assets/icon.png for mdpi, then what should i use for ldpi ? since the lowest one 1.0x isnt defined by additional folder and it's considered as lowest.

Comment: You can create 0.75x folder under images like 'images/0.75x/my_icon.png'

Answer (score 2):

How Flutter handles multi-resolution images is explained [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#declaring-resolution-aware-image-assets).

It comes basically down to this:

> AssetImage understands how to map a logical requested asset onto one that most closely matches the current device pixel ratio. In order for this mapping to work, assets should be arranged according to a particular directory structure: (...)

An example:

> ```
> .../my_icon.png
> .../2.0x/my_icon.png
> .../3.0x/my_icon.png
> ```

Comment: which image should be used (xxhdpi,mdi,hdpi etc) when using with image Asset